# Need help working with python files in different directories

Tags: python, import

First, I have read many threads on this - so I understand it looks like a dupe. But, let me clarify why I still felt the need to post this question - most answers are at least 4 years old and I am hoping that python has introduced better ways to do this.
Here goes. I have a python project with the the following structure:

```
project1/__main__.py

        constants.py
        |

        |__folder1/mod1.py
               
                 __init__.py
```

I am trying to run main.py from the project1 dir (this code in turn calls a function in mod1.py).
In mod1.py, I am trying to import constants.py using (and I tried all the below options)

```
  #1 from constants import * [results in error - NameError: name 'constants' is not defined]
  #2 from ..constants import * [results in error - ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package]
  #3 from project1.constants import * [results in error = ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'projec1']
```

As you can see, none of the above options are working. I would rather not use the sys option recommended in many of the threads. Is there any other clean way to do this? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You should have misspelled something.

```
from constants import *
```

and

```
import constants
```

should work for the structure you've provided.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Interestingly  from constants import  * doesn't work, but import constants worked. Perhaps because constants.py has no class defined but just a long list of constants?

Comment: If you see how the import works: „e.g. foo.bar.baz. In this case, Python first tries to import foo, then foo.bar, and finally foo.bar.baz. If any of the intermediate imports fail, a ModuleNotFoundError is raised.“ So if `import constants` works, `from constants import *` should work too. But it raises `NameError` instead of ModuleNotFoundError, so there is something in the constants.py which raises NameError. Please provide the full stacktrace and the code of `constants.py`.

Comment: It is strange that `import constants` works and `from constants import *` don't, because if I am right, both of them shouldn't work. The import system executes the module's code, so if there is a NameError in the constants.py it should be raised by both of the import statements.

Comment: About your considerations about the content of constants.py see: [importing](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-importing). You are making whatever you have in the one module available to the other. It doesn't matter if you've got classes, functions, etc. You are making them available in the current module's namespace.